# making a div tag dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a module of the project and I seemed to have stuck up. Tell me explain me what I am trying to do.

I have a text box where the user of my web portal will post the facebook like box code, either a fbml code or xfml code.As soon as the user clicks the submit buttton he should be able to see that like box on my site.

But whats happening right now with me is that I am not able to see the like box .
I have put upon the code below,

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
</title> Facebook like widget </title>
<script type="text/javascript"/>



function display_fb()

{
var fburl= document.getElementById('fb_link').value;
document.write(fburl);




}
</script>

</head>
<body> 

<h1>IF YOU HAVE ANY FACEBOOK FAN PASTE THE LINK HERE!!!</h1>

    <label> Paste the link here<input type="text"  id="fb_link"/> </label>
    <input type="button" value="submit"  onClick="display_fb();" />
    <div id="userFBLink" >
    <label>Wanted is here:</label>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I guess need to refresh the div tag once the user puts his facebook like box code.

Comment: If this is really your code, you should first check the syntax. `<script type="text/javascript"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I didn't understand you wrong and you want to add the text of this input into that div as a label (I'll suggest you to use "span" instead, because "label" is for labeling form fields).

It seems that you are looking for that:

```
function display_fb()
{
  var fburl= document.getElementById("fb_link").value;

  var lblLink = document.createElement("span");
  lblLink.appendChild(document.createTextNode(fbUrl));
  document.getElementById("userFBLink").appendChild(lblLink);
}
```

Or with jQuery:

```
function display_fb()
{
   var lblLink = $("<span></span>");
   lblLink.append($("input#fb_link").val());

   $("div#userFBLink").append(lblLink);
}
```

It's up to you!